# Providing a logical rebuttal to "What's the harm?"-type questions

Tags: rhetoric

I have a manager at work who often comes up with shortsighted ideas and then expects his staff to adopt them. On occasions, my colleagues (his staff) will suggest improvements to his ideas that offer demonstrable, measurable positive impact--representing a superior idea. Despite efforts, however, the manager often struggles to grasp the superior idea we put forth and instead bullheadedly adopts his original idea, asking "What's the *harm* in doing it my way?"

The logic/language issue I want to discuss here is the use of the word *harm*. When an idea is sub-optimal or simply shortsighted, it doesn't mean that it must be harmful. It just might be inferior. By putting the team in the position of having to explain what's *harmful* about his inferior ideas, we lose sight of what's about dumb about it! We're often left at a loss for words because he's asking a question that doesn't apply. What he *should* be asking is "why is your idea better?" or "why is my idea inferior?"--but not "why is my idea harmful?" any more than he should be asking "why is my idea funny?" I believe this manager has learned that by asking a question that nearly always will have "nothing" as its answer, he is able to advance bad ideas. And that's actually the real harm...

What is an effective rebuttal to such misdirected questions as "what's the harm"? Surely, this is a logical fallacy of some sort--I just don't know enough about logic to know (but I sense it!). The question is loaded because if there is no harm to speak of then you have to reply "there is no harm"--then you get a gleeful "Well, then, if there's no harm then let's go with my idea!" response.

To point out to the manager that it's not a question of harm, it's a question of "which idea is intrinsically better?" might be a start; but are there tried-and-true rebuttals to this misguided way of defending one's inferior ideas?

Comment: the "harm" is known as opportunity cost. That being said, I would suggest an edit- this is more a question of rhetoric, then it is of propositional logic.

Comment: Be aware that if your boss is really like this, you aren't likely to gain any points with him by arguing. What he wants is for *his* idea to be used, as long as it doesn't clearly make him look bad (that's the "harm" he's talking about - a consequence that would make him look bad). You can suggest alternatives, but if he's not immediately persuaded, he may consider further argument to be a challenge to his authority.

Comment: Yes, great points. But what if the boss is appointed as a result of the Peter Principle and by implementing his ideas we're all going to be aboard a sinking ship? I might have put more emphasis on the "boss" role--he's more of a lead and we're all team players with the charter to do what's best for the company and our customers--and in this case the "boss" is not always right. I don't want to be too crass, but he's a bit of a dim bulb, if you catch my drift.

Comment: Probably a better fit for workplace SE.

Comment: I agree with Papuseme.  There might be no apparent harm to the company, when the only  comparison is between the current status quo and the results of whatever decision the boss wants to make. But there is a loss when the comparison is between the boss’s so-so idea and the future improved situation of the company if alternatives are adopted.

Comment: Is your goal to win an argument or to get the team going in the right direction? If it's the latter, then assuming you are describing your boss accurately, the most effective method is to get him to see the problems by playing dumb and asking questions until he comes up with the right answer and thinks it was his idea. The point is, as much as possible, to ask *dumb* questions, not challenging questions. Challenging questions will get his defenses up. Dumb questions will make him feel smart and insightful when he sees a problem in his original idea.

Comment: I appreciate these comments. I mulled over the question further and feel that the "harm" also is that the lead asks for "suggestions" and "feedback" to his ideas then nearly always goes with his original idea despite receiving constructive feedback from engaged staff members. So there is harm to morale (if anything) in sending a constant "it's my way or the highway" message to team-mates while also championing the idea of being open to any and all input from people who appear to be smarter.